# Cannot find symbol... - Java

Tags: java, oop, syntax-error, symbols

I am new to OOP concepts, and I get an error: cannot find symbol. Also during compilation, i get the 2 errors:

```
Error:(9, 35) java: <identifier> expected
Error:(9, 36) java: illegal start of type
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Here are my two classes:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    TestClass waterBottle = new waterBottle();
    waterBottle.bottleFill(5);
}

package com.company;

public class TestClass {

    TestClass() { }

    public void waterBottleFill(int y) {
        int bottleFill = y;
        System.out.println("Fill level is at:" + bottleFill);
    }

    public void waterBottleRefill(int x) {
        int refill = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your file name? Is java installed in your system. I believe you are getting error in CLI.

Comment: both classes are in differnt java files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
TestClass waterBottle = new TestClass();
waterBottle.bottleFill(5);
```

is actually located in a class definition.

Move this code to your `main` method:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass waterBottle = new waterBottle();
        waterBottle.bottleFill(5);
    }
}
```

This problem becomes obvious and plain when you format your code properly - with identation, vertical and horizontal spacing. I have edited your question, so that it is formatted properly now. Take a look and notice how readable it is now.

Another one problem is your class object creation. You have provided an incorrect name at `new waterBottle()` line. `new` should be followed by a proper class name:

```
TestClass waterBottle = new TestClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    //TestClass waterBottle = new waterBottle(); // what is waterbottle.. this will give you can not find symbol`
    TestClass waterBottle = new TestClass();//should be this


        waterBottle.bottleFill(5);
}// main method ends

}// class ends




package com.company;

public class TestClass {

TestClass(){}

public void waterBottleFill(int y){
    int bottleFill = y;
    System.out.println("Fill level is at:"+ bottleFill);

}
public void waterBottleRefill(int x){
    int refill = x;
}


}
```